# How can I install doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

When I run `composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle` from CMD I get these cryptic messages:

```
Using version ^4.1 for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle
./composer.json has been updated

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle ^4.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle[4.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.1.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^4.3.3|^5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/options-resolver[v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v5.0.4, v5.0.5].
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v4.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - don't install symfony/options-resolver v5.0.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.37
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.4.37, required as 3.4.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.37].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What I undesrstand is I need to uninstall symfony/symfony in order to install doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle. Either I'm mistaken or the I don't understand what the messages mean.

Comment: The package you want to install is not compatible with Symfony 3. You need to upgrade to >= 4.3, or install an older version of the package that supports Sf 3 (not sure there is any)

Comment: Which parts of that error message are unclear? `doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle 4.1.0 requires symfony/options-resolver ^4.3.3|^5.0` - isn't that pretty clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the infos on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle#4.1.0) the version 4+ is not compatible with Symfony 3.

However, the version 3.6.1 (the lastest of the 3.x) is compatible with Symfony 3.4

To specify this version, use

```
composer require doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle:3.6.1
```